# Form validation in thymeleaf by Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to the Springboot and Thymeleaf, I am creating a web where i am using form validation where I am trying to validate fields from an entity class to validate non empty fields.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public class Student {

@NotBlank(message = "Name required")
public String name;
@NotBlank(message = "email required")
public String email;
@NotBlank(message = "address required")
public String address;
@NotBlank(message = "username required")
public String username;
@NotBlank(message = "password required")
public String password;

'''
constructor
getter and setter
'''
}
```

It is not showing error in my html file, showing error on server.
If any one has any idea please help me.

Comment: please share html file

Answer (score 1):

In order this to work add @valid annotation next to @ModelAttribute("student").

```
    public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result, Model model){
```

And also try adding @NotEmpty above the field of Student entity. @NotEmpty will check if the object has empty strings.

Comment: Controller needs to be `@Validated`

Comment: @silentsudo can you provide your controller class and HTML file

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, Model model){
...
}
```

Also, add @NotNull on entity attributes and check once.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
    public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result, Model model){
```

Also, add @NotNull on entity attributes and check once.